# WrapPanel does not redraw on maximize

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.5

I am using wrappanel (WPF 4.5) inside ListView (itemspanel template). 
When I resize the window, wrappanel redraws itself correctly.

When I maximize it, it does not redraw itself.

Below is the code(XAML)

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="3" Width="200" Height="200">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=Window}}" ></WrapPanel>   
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>    
        </ListView>
```

Below are the screenshots
Normal
[image]

Resize  (everthing is alright)
[image]

Maximized (problem, look at red curve spot, listview/wrappanel is supposed to redraw and fill this with subsequent sample images)
[image]

Comment: Remove the `Width` binding. It's wrong and unnecessary.

Comment: without that, it is not wrapping up, and putting horizonal scrollbar only. Never goes up to second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is you have binded **`Width`** of Wrap panel to width of window which will remain constant always what you have specified in XAML.

***Replace Width with ActualWidth*** which always updated with current width of window.

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: a quick question, why does **Width** work on resizing.